# check next array element is same or not in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to check that next Element in my array is same

```js
const p = ['12', '13', '13', '14', '15', '15', '16']

var len = p.length



for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) {


    var d1 = p[i]
        // document.write(d1)


    for (j = i + 1; j <= i + 1; j++) {
        var d2 = p[j]
            // document.write(d2)
        if (d1 == d2) {

            console.log(d1)
            console.log(d2)

        } else {
            console.log(d1)
            console.log('oops!')
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

Here I have **7 Elements** in my array in which same element is same as their before element but some are not.

**What I want** : If the next Element of my Element is not the same with the first one so automatically it print **opps** in place of next and then check for next. as I write in my  code but my code is correct

**Output I want** = `12 oops 13 13 14 oops 15 15 16 oops`

**Output I'm geeting**= `12 oops! 13 13 13 oops! 14 oops! 15 15 15 oops! 16 oops!`

Anyone help me with this? I don't know what to do.

**Thank You**

Comment: clone it then check

Comment: @FredRandall already this I want output ```12 oops 13 13 14 oops 15 15 16 oops

``` this which I'm not getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure that I understand logic and how to handle all edge cases, but here is variant which fits provided expected output:

```js
const p = ['12', '13', '13', '14', '15', '15', '16']
let len = p.length;

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(p[i]);
    if (i+1 >= len || p[i] != p[i+1])
        console.log('oops!'); // print oops only if we're at the end of the array OR elements are different
    else
      console.log(p[i++]); // this will run only if we're before the end of array AND numbers are the same
}
```

note: what about multiple (more than 2) consecutive equal numbers?

Comment: @llya Bursov no bro it would not be happen

Answer (score 0):

The output you desire will require varied incrementation of `i` in the loop as you will need to skip the next value when it matches. I suggest using a `while` loop so that you can conditionally control the incrementation of `i`. I have changed the logging logic to further illustrate my point:

```js
const p = ['12', '13', '13', '14', '15', '15', '16']
const len = p.length
let i = 0

while (i < len) {

  const next = i + 1

  if (p[i] == p[next]) {
    console.log(i, p[i], p[next])

    // extra increment when match found
    i++

  } else {
    console.log(i, p[i], 'oops!')
  }

  // always increment by 1
  i++

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can skip the second loop. If it is only the very next element you need to compare to the current one, just do `p[i + 1]`, check whether it is not outside of the array, then compare the two.

```js
const p = ['12', '13', '13', '14', '15', '15', '16']
var len = p.length;
for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) {
    var d1 = p[i]
    var d2 = typeof(p[i + 1]) !== 'undefined' ? p[i + 1] : '';
    if (d1 == d2) {
        i++
        console.log(d1)
        console.log(d2)

    } else {
        console.log(d1)
        console.log('oops!')
    }
}
```

Comment: @laassiek bro I want pair of two same element if pair of two same element  are present one by one so print them if only one pair is present so print opps in place of next pair. like this ```12 oops 13 13 14 oops 15 15 16 oops ```